# Android Espresso - perform action on recyclerview that was dynamically added to a parent view

Tags: android-espresso

I'm very new to Espresso, and I feel like this is doable, but I'm not sure exactly how.

I know you can click on a RecyclerView row using:

```
onView(withId(viewId)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(position, click()));
```

The problem I'm having is that in the piece of code I'm testing the RecyclerView is added at runtime.  How do I get the viewId to pass to this function?  Or how else can I get this to work?

Comment: Did you want to perform action on a child view in particular row?

Comment: I want to get a reference to the recyclerview itself.  It is a child view of a container view, which I have the id for, but it's added to the container view programmatically at runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the RecyclerView does not have an id, you can still use other matchers:

```
// Any RecyclerView
onView(isAssignableFrom(RecyclerView.class)).perform(...);

// RecyclerView that is a child/descendant of a container view
onView(allOf(isAssignableFrom(RecyclerView.class), isDescendantOfA(withId(container_id)))).perform(...);
```

Comment: this is very close to the answer, but there are multiple recyclerviews, so now I'm getting an error: "AmbiguousViewMatcherException
This matcher matches multiple views in the hierarchy".  Is there a way to just pick the first view?

Comment: hmm, how unique is the recycler view? And how are they laid out in this "container" view? Can you post a snippet of xml layout or code?

Comment: This did solve the original problem, I think I can figure it out from here.  Thanks you rock!